# SQL Server - need assistance with sum and case statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005.  I'm looking to add up the columns (AM, Midday, Evening) to see which ones contains the value "YES" and then take that total and multiply it by the rate for each row for a client.

Here is the query I have so far:

```
Select 
Sum(Case When morning = 'yes' Then 1 Else 0 End) am_total,
Sum(Case When midday = 'yes' Then 1 Else 0 End) midday_total
From services
where client_id = 24
```

with the following output

```
am_total    midday_total  
45          49
```

When I introduce the rate variable, my query starts telling me I need the group_by clause and I don't think I'm ready for that since I still need to add the am_total and the midday_total together first and then multiply that by the rate.

Ultimately, all I'm looking for is the grand total.

Comment: Is the `rate` a column of that table, or something from elsewhere? (I'm not sure I understand your problem because you say "multiply by the rate _for each row_ for a client", then you say you need to total first and then multiply by the rate.)

Comment: why do you need rate? What that variable represent, is it table attribute or declared variable?

Comment: A client can have multiple rows in the database.  The rate is a dynamic variable that is unique to each row.  I need to get the total for each for row and then add all the rows together to get a grand total for the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, maybe this is what you need

```
declare @rate int
set @rate = 2 /*what ever rate is */

select am_total * @rate as am, midday_total * @rate as midday
from (
  Select 
   Sum(Case When morning = 'yes' Then 1 Else 0 End) am_total,
   Sum(Case When midday = 'yes' Then 1 Else 0 End) midday_total
  From services
  where client_id = 24
)
```

You can also join another table and use its columns in calculation

```
  Select 
   Sum(Case When morning = 'yes' Then 1 * u.rate Else 0 End) am_total,
   Sum(Case When midday = 'yes' Then 1 * u.rate Else 0 End) midday_total
  From services srv inner join users u on services.id = u.service_id -- assuming this is relation
```

pay attention on **u.rate** above

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  I'm coding this for a web page (using coldfusion).  Looks like using your method, I'd need to make a stored procedure out of this and then going that way, I could pass the rate to the stored proc.  I'll try this and report back shortly, I hope. :)

Comment: client_id will also be a variable I'd need to pass but I can work on that one I get it working for one client.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it is not producing the results I need (or I'm implementing it incorrectly).  What else do you have? :)

Comment: if you have user specific rate, you can calculate specific rate inside case statement, for instance { Sum(Case When morning = 'yes' Then some_filed* other_field/ constant Else 0 End) am_total } .... but remember, it is only in case when morning = 'YES' is set in row, and only those attributes which are in that row will be multiplied

Comment: I have another question, "What?"

Comment: Okay, this is working:
`Select 
   Sum(Case When morning = 'yes' Then 1 * srv.rate Else 0 End) am_total,
   Sum(Case When midday = 'yes' Then 1 * srv.rate Else 0 End) midday_total
  From services srv inner join customer u on srv.client_id = u.client_id
  where u.client_id = 24`  Now, I just need to add the totals together to get a grand total for client id of 24.

Comment: add another sum in SELECT statement.... Sum(Case When midday = 'yes' Then 1 * srv.rate WHEN morning = 'yes' Then 1 * srv.rate ELSE 0 End) as GrandTotal   or wrap result in another select, like in first example in answer above and add those two calculated columns SELECT am_total, midday_total, am_total + midday_total as grand_total

Comment: I finally got there with some modification and some coldfusion help.  Thans, @milan-naric !